# mongodb/mongojs won't update with put

Tags: mongodb, express, mean-stack, mongojs

I am working on a simple CRUD app using MEAN stack and I was testing my server to ensure that I could perform requests on my mongodb database. I was able to perform GET, POST and DELETE requests but when I use postman to perform a PUT request, I get this as a response

```
{
    "driver": true,
    "name": "MongoError"
}
```

Here is my code for performing PUT requests:

```
router.put('/todo/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    var todo = req.body;
    var updTodo = {};

    if(todo.title){
        updTodo.title = todo.title;
    }
    if(!updTodo){
        res.status(400);
        res.json({
            error : "Bad Data"
        });
    } else  {
        db.todos.update(
            {_id : mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, updTodo, {}, function (error, todo) {
            if (error){
                res.send(error);
            }
            res.json(todo);
        });
    }
});
```

I'm new to Express so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Edit: This is what the request looks like:[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbPIm.png)

Comment: can you share what the PUT request looks like, Including the body?

Comment: Edited to include screenshot of the request

Comment: MongoDB recently updated their drivers, maybe try updating your driver to version 4.2?

Comment: @Blak : Try changing your body type to `raw` & put a JSON overthere in postman..

Comment: That didn't change the error. I have updated my driver as well.